# What is the difference between full octave and half octave pyramid?

Tags: computer-vision

- I couldn't find a good source to explain the diffrence between the **Full octave** and **Half Octave** pyramid in **Computer-Vision**.
- I saw the [**Gaussian-Pyramid**](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html?highlight=pyramids#skimage.transform.pyramid_gaussian), and the [**Laplacian Pyramid**](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html?highlight=pyramids#skimage.transform.pyramid_laplacian), but I didn't see anything about Full Octave - Half Octave Pyramids!
- Can anybody please explain the difference between **Half** and **Full Octave** Pyramids?

Comment: https://www.slideserve.com/barrett-kennedy/advanced-computer-vision , 

https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Two-octaves-of-the-image-pyramid-each-made-of-five-images-i-of-scale-factor-k-i-s0_fig1_229140310